# Dynamics 365 App for Outlook "Company" Field not syncing with Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I have only just started working with Dynamics 365 so I have very limited knowledge. My apologies.

I pushed out the Dynamics 365 App for Outlook and I've gone to track a address book contact in Outlook. This worked and I can see the contact created in Dynamics 365.

However, the "Company" field in outlook has not synced with the "Company Name" field in "Contacts" Dynamics 365.

I've searched far and wide for a fix and spent most of the day researching how to fix this.

Is this by design and I need to make a configuration change like creating a relationship between the 2 fields?

I have reinstalled the client and that has not resolved the issue. I also manually created the company name as an account and tried another sync and it didn't pick up the association either.

Can somebody please assist. Many Thanks

Updated: Added in Screen Shots of Synchronization Settings.

```
[Contact Synchronization Settings Part 1][1]
[Contact Synchronization Settings Part 2][2]
[Contact Synchronization Settings Part 3][3]
[Contact Synchronization Settings Part 4][4]
[Contact Synchronization Settings Part 5][5]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcbFG.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n71l8.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/27urf.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAuFU.png
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxqSb.png
```

When I look at the Dynamics 365 Field in the Sync settings this is what I see:

Parent (Regarding)  Bidirectional   Company Name (Regarding)

I would expect to see something like this?

**Company** (Regarding) Bidirectional   Company Name (Regarding)

Thanks

Comment: can you provide some screen shots of the current Outlook Client configs/mappings?

Comment: Hi @J.S.Orris, Thanks for the response. I have added in Screen Caps of the Synchronization settings under personalization settings in Dynamics 365. Hopefully this is what you requested. Please let me know if not and ill amend. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Again @J.S.Orris. I think I may have found the reason why. This link explains it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/outlook-addin/user-guide/track-outlook-contacts. "The Company field for an Outlook contact is not automatically added to the parent account of the new Dynamics 365 for Customer Engagement contact."